# Trouble using WhenAnyValue with WhenAnyObservable

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to avoid an update to a property if another property is changing. So I've come up with the following (in my ViewModel):

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(
    x => x.WhenAnyValue( y => y.Asset.CurrentValuation ),
    x => x.Changing,
    (currentValuation, changing) => changing.PropertyName != "CurrentValuationCalculated"
)
```

However, ReactiveUI throws the following error inside `ExpressionRewriter.VisitMethodCall`:

```
throw new NotSupportedException("Index expressions are only supported with constants.")
```

If I remove the `WhenAnyValue` line, it works. So I'm assuming it's something to do with the expression inside `WhenAnyValue`?

Without delving into what the `ExpressionRewriter` code actually does, what is it complaining about? Have I made some sort of simple error?

**Update**

So I've entered this instead:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(
    x => x.Asset.CurrentValuation,
    x => x.Changing,
    ( currentValuation, changing ) => changing.PropertyName != "CurrentValuationCalculated"
)
```

However, the compiler complains about `x.Asset.CurrentValuation` and says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'System.IObservable<ReactiveUI.IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<ReactiveUI.IReactiveObject>>'
```

Comment: `WhenAnyValue` only accepts Property. Can you double check `y.Asset.CurrentValuation` is property, NOT method?

Comment: Good question, I hadn't double checked. However, `Asset` and `Asset.CurrentValuation` are both properties

Comment: What is the `Asset.CurrentValuation` datatype?

Comment: A nullable decimal

Comment: try changing `x => x.WhenAnyValue( y => y.Asset.CurrentValuation )` to `x => x.Asset.CurrentValuation`, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

The longer answer is `WhenAnyObservable` will provide you the change notification, so you don't really need the `WhenAnyValue`.  You would generally use `WhenAnyValue` on a ViewModel property to force a subscription to the change notification.  The observable sequence is inherently providing change notification via `OnNext`

### Edit

Notice below I am observing an `IObservable` in the `WhenAnyObservable` and a view model property in `WhenAnyValue`.  You don't need to unwrap the value in the call to `WhenAnyObservable` to get the value out.

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _property;

    public IObservable<bool> MyObservabe { get; }

    public string MyProperty { get => _property; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _property, value); }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyObservabe = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(x => x > 5);

        this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.MyObservabe);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example to illustrate your answer?

Comment: Try making the WhenAnyValue portion its own member property and then use that property, instead. this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.CurrentValuation, x => x.Changing)

Comment: I thought that `x.CurrentValuation` was a property - and not an Observable and that's why you had to use `WhenAnyValue`, to turn a property into an Observable. As seen in this response - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21342186/23401

Comment: But what if I want to get up-to-date values of each at the same time? Originally, I just had `this.WhenAnyValue( x => x.Asset.CurrentValuation )`. But then I wanted to avoid the `Subscribe` if `CurrentValuationCalculated` is in the process of changing - which is only accessible via the `Changing` property/observable

Comment: Though I think my original logic is flawed. Setting `CurrentValuationCalculated` to true will auto-calculate `CurrentValuation` - but only **after** `CurrentValuationCalculated` has been changed! Still, I'm under the impression that the original statement should be possible - hence the question

Comment: The answer to your question is yes you can do what you want.  `WhenAnyValue` will emit an observable sequence.  I think your problem with your update is that you are looking a `x.Changing` which I believe is `this` changing which should be the View Model.  You might want to do `x.Property.Changing` to look at the property that is changing.