# WhenAnyObservable throws with message 'Index expressions are only supported with constants.'

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I would like to observe a property path: `MainViewModel.Project.SelectedDocument.Align`

1. `Align` is regular property of type `ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit>`.
2. `Project` and `SelectedDocument` are regular properties.

I'm using this to create the observable (from `MainViewModel`):

```
var commandObs = this
    .WhenAnyObservable(x => x.Project.SelectedDocument.WhenAnyValue(y => y.Align));
```

I'm getting an exception on this line with the following message:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Index expressions are only supported with constants.'

What's wrong?

Since the `WhenAnyObservable` method requires an observable property at the end of the property path, I'm creating it with the inner WhenAnyValue. Is that the problem? Should the property expression a simple access expression instead of a method call?

In any case, I took the code from this answer: [ReactiveUI How to use WhenAnyObservable properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317264/reactiveui-how-to-use-whenanyobservable-properly)

It supposedly works :) but not for me in this case.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: This could be an issue/protecetion from an issue with Lambda Variable Capture: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c/ | Similar to how we added the CrossThreadException back in .NET 2.0. So people would finally use invoke (and avoid the issues it is there to solve): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806/3346583

Answer (score 3):

Expressions in the `WhenAny` must point towards a property or field. That's why reactiveui is throwing the exception. You would need to expose an `IObservable` property or you could use a `Select` and `Switch` statements.

Eg

```cs
var commandObs = this
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.Project.SelectedDocument)
    .Select(x => x.WhenAnyValue(y => y.Align))
    .Switch()
```